# ArrayList vs char[]. which is most efficient for building into a large string

Tags: java, performance, parsing, arraylist, character-arrays

I am reading a data in byte-by-byte.  when i have determined that i have an entire message, i need to pass it to another function as a string.  Some messages can be quite large, but the sizes vary frequently.  Which implementation do you all feel is most effecient:

```
public test class
{
   char[] buffer = new char[MAX_SIZE_7200];
   int bufferIndex = 0;
   void parseData(ArrayList<Byte> msg, length)
   {
       while (!msg.isEmpty())
       {
          buffer[bufferIndex++] = (char) msg.remove(0);
          if (isfullmessage)
          {
             parseData(new String(buffer, 0, bufferIndex);
             bufferIndex = 0;  //restart and continue parsing data
          }
       }
   }
 }
```

OR:

```
public test class
{
   List<Character> buffer = new ArrayList<Character>();
   int bufferIndex = 0;
   void parseData(ArrayList<Byte> msg, length)
   {
       while (!msg.isEmpty())
       {
          buffer.add((char) msg.remove(0));
          if (isfullmessage)
          {
              StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(buffer.size());
              for (Character ch: buffer)
              {
                  builder.append(ch);
              }
              parseData(builder.toString());
              buffer.clear();
          }
       }
   }
 }
```

OR:

```
public test class
    {
       StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
       int bufferIndex = 0;
       void parseData(ArrayList<Byte> msg, length)
       {
           while (!msg.isEmpty())
           {
              buffer.append((char) msg.remove(0));
              if (isfullmessage)
              {                  
                  parseData(builder.toString());
                  buffer.clear();  //some stringbuilder clear function
              }
           }
       }
     }
```

or is there a more efficient way.  Please note that i have the variables holding my finished message outside the scope of the function since i might process data that does not contain a full message and may take multiple executions of the function to get a full message and process it.

Comment: use `StringBuilder` in java.lang

Comment: they both could be optimized

Comment: And for msg use ByteArrayOutputStream (byte[]) or maybe ByteBuffer.

Comment: Did you try timing them?  Or do you expect us to know what CPU, OS, JVM, and data you're using?

Comment: @cHao - I did do some timing, but that doesn't always equal best use of resources.

Comment: i hope you are only ever getting 7-bit ascii data, otherwise your byte -> char "conversion" is going to break.

Comment: @jtahlborn - Yes, it will always be 1 byte per character.

Comment: Maybe check the performance of calls to `msg.remove(0)` as well.

Comment: @fgb - I'm aware that the remove(0) is probably pretty performance intensive, but in my scenario, it is acting as a type of queue with data getting added to at the end and removed from the front.

Comment: @Jason: Then perhaps *use* a Queue.  A `LinkedList` might be useful, if you're always adding at one end and removing from the other.  Might be a bit overkill for single chars, though...

Comment: +1 to cHao and fgb - `ArrayList.remove(0)` is an incredibly wasteful operation, better to just loop over each item in the list, or if you really need a queue, use something that implements [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).  It supports appending characters one at a time, expands capacity as needed, and can be reset for reuse purposes.

Comment: That or StringBuffer. They have slightly different purposes apparently.

Comment: @Vipar StringBuilder differs from StringBuilding in that StringBuilder is not synchronized and therefore should be more performant where there are no multi-threading concerns.

Comment: Is it safer to define some minimum capacity and expand as needed, or leave the constructor blank?

Comment: also, this code is running in a single point of entry thread and the data will not be stepped on.  The example code is a very simplified example of what my code actually does.

Comment: @Jason The default, initial capacity is 16 characters.  If you know your messages are going to be larger than that, by all means use one of the specialized constructors.

Comment: @Vipar StringBuffer is needed if you have an old API which requires it.  There is no good reason for StringBuffer to be synchronized IMHO, so use STringBuilder as the API suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the average length of your messages. For a more 'full' message, the char will be a better choice since its element type

For the sparse case, the list template will be better as the memory consumption will be lower, despite the overhead of the object presentation

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the elements of the ArrayList msg by removing the first element of this ArrayList in a loop. An ArrayList stores all its elements in an array. Removing the first element is slow, because all elements in the array (except the first one) need to be copied.

So maybe the biggest overhead is not in setting a character in an array or appending a character to a StringBuilder, but maybe the biggest overhead is in the repeated calls to msg.remove(0).

You can fix this by using this:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < msg.length()) {
    buffer[bufferIndex++] = (char) msg.get(index);
    index++;
    // etc.
}
```